# Recording Audio Stream in Background in Windows phone 7/8

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I m developing an app which can record audio stream.
I want to know that is it possible to record that audio in background, i,e when the application is in deactivated mode?
I have already tried to do that in many different ways,but its not helping out.
Please suggest me some way to do such...

Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to get it to work under the lock screen or when the app is in the background? If it's the latter, you will run into problems. WP8 is a one-program OS. The only things you can really do from the background are notifications, scheduled tasks, file transfers, and audio. None of those will support what you're trying to do.

Comment: As i know background audio Playback is possible using background audio player, similarly can i record something in background or under the lock screen, if i use background worker ... will it work?

Comment: Playback != recording though. None of the APIs or classes seem to have anything that would allow for background recording.

How is the recording initiated? Is it just supposed to just run constantly? Does it have to run in the background, or is it sufficient to work under the lock screen only?

Comment: http://www.windowsphone.com/en-in/store/app/free-recorder/d79e9518-3104-410c-b469-f68735e0c88c   i have seen this app is recording under the lock screen.. please refer.

Comment: Yes, running under lock screen and running in the background are VERY different tasks. Background implies that another application has focus. Under the lock screen implies your app has focus ( and therefore can execute normally ) but the phone is locked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, it's **not** possible to record in the background.

Your app must be running in the *foreground* for it to be able to record audio using the microphone. For an overview of all the audio recording options, please refer to [this tutorial on the Nokia Developer Wiki](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Audio_recording_and_playback_options_in_Windows_Phone).

Also, an app will not run when the phone is locked - it is suspended. So if your app was recording, it would stop when the phone is locked. You can change this behaviour with [`IdleDetectionMode.Disabled`](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Run_Windows_Phone_application_under_lock_screen) which means your app keeps running even though the phone is locked.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't implemented it before, but classifying it as a VOIP app could be the way to go:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207046(v=vs.105).aspx